# Make grep search all folders?

Tags: php, shell

I have code that will grep through all files in a cpanel but am unsure what arguments to use in the shell command.

Currently this is the line of code going into shell_exec():
    $command = "grep -il '.$term.' ./*";

This is only searching the files in the folder that this script is in.  Adding the -r argument does not fix it nor does -d recursive.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the below has worked for me, still looking for some help.   I should be clearer in that I want the effects of the arguments -i, -l, and -r but adding -r doesn't change the output at all for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -exec grep -il '.$term.' {} \;`

The '\' may be unnecessary on windows machines but will be necessary on *nix

Comment: It does if you've added it (via cygwin for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -r "some string" <dir>
```

This will recursively search all directories below `dir`

Hope it helps.

Comment: OP specifically says "adding the -r argument does not fix it".

Comment: What I think he forgot is the "dir" parameter.

Comment: You are right, but then the problem might be that he needs to use "." instead